# Can I check how much space my indexedDB is taking up?

Tags: browser, storage, indexeddb

I'd like to get a breakdown of how much storage space a web app I'm working on is taking up. More specifically I'm interested in the size of data stored in indexedDB.

I know I can use `navigator.storage.estimate()` to get a total value, but it shows over 1 mbyte even with an empty db, and I'm interested in knowing the size of indexedDB specifically.

Is there a way to check the size?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- **Chrome/Edge/Opera Only**: [`navigator.storage.estimate().usageDetails`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/estimate#usagedetails) provides a breakdown by storage type, but it's not supported in Firefox/Safari (see [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/estimate#browser_compatibility))

> Note: The returned values are not exact: between compression, deduplication, and obfuscation for security reasons, they will be imprecise.

---

- In **Chrome DevTools**, the **Application** tab provides a breakdown of storage by type; click the "Clear storage" view in the top left and a graph should appear. This is useful for local debugging, but not understanding storage usage "in the wild"

Comment: I see that there is 15.1 MB used with my indexeddb .  It is 172,000 records with key and value pair  , the value is json data of several fields.     What is interesting is that It says   15.1 MB used out of 16625 MB of storage data in Chrome browser.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can make use of the **Quota Management API** to get these information. this is an experimental feature and currently not supported by EDGE

**[This](https://demo.agektmr.com/storage/)** site will give you information how Browser support this and can see in real

Example

```
// Query current usage and availability in Temporary storage:
navigator.storageQuota.queryInfo("temporary").then(
  function(storageInfo) {
    // Continue to initialize local cache using the obtained
    // usage and remaining space (quota - usage) information.
    initializeCache(storageInfo.usage,
                    storageInfo.quota - storageInfo.usage);
  });
```

More reading is available in [W3org](https://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/)

Comment: The links from that page go to deprecated posts. Looks like navigator.storageQuota been replaced by navigator.storage, which I mentioned in my question.

Comment: May i know why the negative vote so that i can correct  it